# How to change multiple products status by specific SKU in magento 1.9 Myql query?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, database

How to i can change multiple products status by specific SKU in magento 1.9 with Myql query ? i have lot of products disabled but i want specific products enabled by SKU with Mysql query or programming. how to i'll do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally i create this query for update status of multiple configurable products with Mysql query.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int cpei, catalog_product_entity cpe
SET cpei.value = "1"
WHERE cpe.entity_id = cpei.entity_id
AND cpe.sku IN ('0104421', '0105777');
```